# Query tables using lookup table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, lookup-tables

I'm tryng to query tables using a lookup table, this because the tables have a differente name/code for a same value.

For example, `Employee` and `Production` tables have same field of `Site`, but they have it named differently.So I want the field `Person` from `Employee` and `Percent` from `Production`, this joining being done through the same `Site`.

```
=Employee=
id | Person   | Site
---+----------+------
 1 | Joe      | Mex
 2 | Sally    | MXN
 3 | Eric     | Mex
 4 | John     | USA

=Production=
id |     %    | Site
---+----------+------
 1 |    98    | Mexico
 2 |    97    | USA
 3 |    98    | India
 4 |    96    | Thailand


=SiteCode=
id | Site     | Sitecode
---+----------+------
 1 | Mexico   | Mex
 2 | Mexico   | MXN
 3 | USA      | USA
 4 | USA      | Unite States of America
```

Output desired:

```
 Person   | %
----------+------
 Joe      | 98
 Sally    | 98
 Eric     | 98
 John     | 97
```

Already tried something along the lines of:

```
select Employee.Person, Production.Percent
from
Employee INNER JOIN SiteCode
on Employee.Site = SiteCode.Sitecode
INNER JOIN SiteCode.Sitecode = Production.Site
```

Any help would be appreciated, just cant wrap my brain around it..

Answer (score 1):

```
select Employee.Person, Production.Percent
from
Employee 
   INNER JOIN SiteCode on Employee.Site = SiteCode.Sitecode
   INNER JOIN Production on SiteCode.Site = Production.Site
```

Answer (score 1):

This is tricky.  You should really fix the data.  But, you can do something like this:

```
with sc as (
      select sc.*,
             (case when sitecode = 'Unite States of America' then 'USA'
                   else sitecode
              end) as new_sitecode
      from sitecode sc
     )
select e.Person, p.percent
from employee e join
     sc
     on e.site = sc.new_sitecode join
     production p
     on p.site = sc.site;
```

Comment: What do you mean fix the data? What would be a good practice for this type of problem? Btw I don't believe this solution is viable for me because I have numerous Sites and SiteCodes, wouldn't that affect performance of query? Thanks for your response!

Comment: @DavidA. . . . You should fix the data so sites and site codes are consistent across the different tables.